# How to avoid input detection when the game window isn't focused with Unity Input System?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, gamepad

I'm using Unity 2020.1.3f and Input System 1.0.2 to create a simple racing multiplayer game with MLAPI 0.1.0 but whenever i start an instance of the game after building it and unfocus the window it still detecting my gamepad input (with keyboard does not happen), but when I play the game in Unity's game view and unfocus the editor it does not detect the input anymore. What can i do to only detect my gamepad input when the window is focused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either detect loss of focus using the Unity Event function `OnApplicationFocus(bool)` ([Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html)) or by checking the current focus state with `Application.isFocused` ([Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isFocused.html)). Then in your input logic ignore gamepad input if focus is `false`

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what i needed